# JQuery click on/off

Tags: jquery

I have the following code but I want to make it do something on click and do something else on click again:

```js
$('#show-nav').on('click', function(){
  $('.mobile-nav').css({ 'height': 'auto' });
});
```

I've looked at lots of examples, mainly using a toggle function, but the code seems so long and complex. I want something short and easy like the hover on/off function below:

```js
$( "td" ).hover(
  function() {
    $( this ).addClass( "hover" );
  }, function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "hover" );
  }
);
```

What's the most efficient way of writing a simple click on/off function? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use variable to toggle the values and determine which click needs to be executed:

```
var isfirst=true;
$('#show-nav').click(function(){
 if(isfirst){
    click1();
 } else {
    click2();
 }
 isfirst= !isfirst;
});
```

Comment: FYI toggle cannot be used like this any more: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/. This code will cause an error.